# archetypes.schemaextender: possible to have default_method

Tags: plone

Archetypes API provides `default_method()` to populate initial values programmatically.

However, since this is a class method, it is not suitable for archetypes.schemaextender. What would be the equivalent approach with the extender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no field.default nor field.default_method you can use IFieldDefaultProvider adapter. See this snippet of code from Archetypes.Field.Field class, getDefault method:

```
if not self.default:
    default_adapter = component.queryAdapter(instance, IFieldDefaultProvider, name=self.__name__)
    if default_adapter is not None:
        return default_adapter()
```

and also IFieldDefaultProvider:

```
class IFieldDefaultProvider(Interface):
    """Register a named adapter for your content type providing
    this interface, with a name that is equal to the name of a
    field. If no default or default_method is set on that field
    explicitly, Archetypes will find and call this adapter.
    """

    def __call__():
        """Get the default value.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution for default_method() when working with archetypes.schemaextender using Mixin class. The code for the initial value of a filed should be in a method named '*getDefault*' within such a mixin class, which you put before the declarations of the extended fields:

```
class ProvideDefaultValue:
""" Mixin class to populate an extention field programmatically """

    def getDefault(self, instance):
        """ Getting value from somewhere (in this ex. from same field of the parent) """
        parent = aq_parent(instance)
        if hasattr(parent, 'getField'):
            parentField = parent.getField(self.__name__)
            if parentField is not None:
                return parentField.getAccessor(parent)
```

Now you can include this method in the corresponding extention class declaration:

```
class StringFieldPrefilled(ExtensionField, ProvideDefaultValue, atapi.StringField):
    """ Extention string field, with default value prefilled from parent. """
```

Note: you do not need to add a default_method in the extended schema field definition.